# How do I deploy php code in GAE once I've connected it to Bitbucket?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

So I connected my Bitbucket to Google App Engine project. I assumed a simple deploy mechanism would be present but I'm unable to find it. I remember in the past there was some kind of pipeline feature that allowed skipping of testing for php and deployment but I no longer see it. Is there a simple way to deploy (skipping unit tests) that doesn't require Jenkins to GAE?

Comment: Well the "push-to-deploy" feature is for Jenkins, so no, not directly. You can use gcloud through command line, so I assume it would be possible to build a script to a- commit your code to bitbucket and then b- upload the code to GAE